# How to check letter by letter using addEventListener 'keydown'?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, keydown

I'm trying to check if is true or false the letter I typed.

for exemplo, I have one String that I caught from a array doing join(' '):

"problem test javascript css pc"

My current code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {

  let count = 0
  let charlist = "problem test javascript css pc"

for(let i = 0; i < charlist.length; i++){
  if(charlist[i] === event.key){
    count++
    console.log(count)
  }

}

 })
```

When I type "s" is counting 2, and when I type "t" is counting 3, there is no sequence..

What I need is check just the first letter "p" and count 1 return true, type letter "r" count 1 return true

how can I test this ?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you just trying to find out if the character is in the string, or do you want to count how many times it occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach than [@Kinglish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978409/14148586) compares the string's current character using the current count.

```js
let count = 0

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {

  let mystring = "problem test javascript css pc"
  
  for(let i = count; i < mystring.length; i++){
    if(event.key == mystring.charAt(i)){
      console.log('correct character')
      count++
      break;
    }
    if (event.key != mystring.charAt(count+1)) {
      console.log('wrong character')
      break;
    } 
  }

})
```

```html
<div>problem test javascript css pc</div>
<input style="margin-top: 10px;" class="typebox" placeholder="type here..."></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you can follow. First you store the phrase as an array, and for every `keydown`, compare the `event.key` with the letter that matches the `counter` index of the phrase array. For each correctly keyed letter, you advance your counter. Look through this code to get an idea of how it works

```js
let keycounter = 0,
  correct = 0,
  wrong = 0;
let response = document.querySelector('.response')
let completed = document.querySelector('.completed')
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {

  let count = 0
  let charlist = "problem test javascript css pc";
   if (charlist.split('')[keycounter] === event.key) {
    completed.innerHTML += event.key
    correct++;
    keycounter++

    response.innerHTML = event.key + ' was correct';
  } else {
    wrong++;
    response.innerHTML = event.key + ' was wrong';
  }

  response.innerText += ' - ' + correct + ' right/' + wrong + ' wrong so far'

  if (correct === charlist.split('').length) response.innerText += +"<br> FINISHED";

})
```

```css
.completed:empty, .response:empty{
display:none;
}

.completed, .response{
margin:5px 0;
padding:5px;
background:#f0f0f0;
}

.response{
color:#666;
}
```

```html
<p>Click in this area and type in this phrase <strong>problem test javascript css pc</strong></p>

<div class='completed'></div>
<div class='response'></div>
```